# Android: One item on the list view is not showing text properly

Tags: android

```
private void initializeListItems() {
    // 1st item (position 0)
    itemRepeatAlarm = new TextOnlyItem();
    itemRepeatAlarm.setTitle(getString(R.string.repeat_weekly));
    itemRepeatAlarm.setSubtitle(getString(R.string.never));
    // add the 1st item to the list adapter
    listAdapter.addItem(itemRepeatAlarm);

    // 2nd item (position 1)
    itemAlarmType = new TextOnlyItem();
    itemAlarmType.setTitle(getString(R.string.alarm_type));
    // set the default option to "sound", which is the first string value in the string array called 'sound_vibrate'.
    itemAlarmType.setSubtitle(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.sound_vibrate)[0]);
    // add the 2nd item to the list adapter
    listAdapter.addItem(itemAlarmType);

    // 3rd item (position 2)
    itemAlarmTypeVolume = new VolumeSeekbarItem();
    // add the 3rd item to the list adapter
    listAdapter.addItem(itemAlarmTypeVolume);

    // 4th item (position 3)
    itemAlarmTone = new TextOnlyItem();
    itemAlarmTone.setTitle(getString(R.string.alarm_tone));
    itemAlarmTone.setSubtitle(getString(R.string.none));
    // add the 4th item to the list adapter
    listAdapter.addItem(itemAlarmTone);

    // 5th item (position 4)
    itemSnooze = new TextAndSwitchItem();
    itemSnooze.setTitle(getString(R.string.snooze));
    itemSnooze.setSubtitle(getString(R.string.snooze_details));
    itemSnooze.check();
    // add the 5th item to the list adapter
    listAdapter.addItem(itemSnooze);

    // 6th item (position 5)
    itemAlarmName = new TextOnlyItem();
    itemAlarmName.setTitle(getString(R.string.alarm_name));
    itemAlarmName.setSubtitle(getString(R.string.none));
    // add the 6th item to the list adapter
    listAdapter.addItem(itemAlarmName);

    // 7th item (position 6)
    itemAlarmLock = new TextOnlyItem();
    itemAlarmLock.setTitle(getString(R.string.alarm_lock));
    // set the name of the first alarm lock option as default.
    itemAlarmLock.setSubtitle(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.alarm_lock_list)[0]);
    // add the 8th item to the list adapter
    listAdapter.addItem(itemAlarmLock);

    // notifyDataSetChanged() method belongs to the BaseAdapter class.
    // Notifies the attached observers that the underlying data has been changed and
    // any View reflecting the data set should refresh itself.
    listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

As I run the code, the others don't have any problems. But the 4th item `itemAlarmTone`, is not showing the subtitle, which I originally expected to have `none`, as you can find out with the following captured image.

[image]

As I have made a research so far, one of the plausible reason for this malfunction is because the layout of the list items are not set to have `match_parent` for their height values. I already looked into the layouts, fixed the value and still it seems to be turning out like that above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was already overriding the `onResume()` method regarding setting the sub-title to the alarm tone item part. After I removed the following part, it started working well.

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    itemAlarmTone.setSubtitle(ringtone);
    listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```